# App crashing with error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception" on changing deployment target to 10.9

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, libstdc++, libc++

I recently changed the deployment target of my app on mac OS X to 10.9 from 10.8. All other things, code, all other settings being the same. And after this change app is crashing on throwing any exception. The error it shows is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception", though the app is actually built against libstd++.

I made the things really simple, and i wrote the following code in the beginning of main function of my app:

```
    try
    {
        int i = 5;
        throw i;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        int j = 0;
        j++;
    }
```

and the app crashes on **"throw i;"**.

The crash stack doesn't give anything either.
[here is a snapshot of call stack and code crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHB4e.png)

Comment: why are you explicitly throwing i ?

Comment: this is just dummy code i wrote , i threw explicitly in the beginning of main to prevent complications, and even on this throw, app crashes.